# CSS file not loading in grav cms using twig

Tags: php, twig, content-management-system, grav

I have the following code in my default theme in grav after a fresh install , the code resides in the in `base.html.twig` file which is basically a `partial` , that gets used in other twig templates like so:

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ page.content }}
{% endblock %}
```

**ISSUE/PROBLEM STATEMENT**:
So i have the following css being loaded in my `base.html.twig` , but when i check loaded page i don't see the `css/custom.css` file , why is this so ? why is the custom.css file not being loaded ?

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/pure-0.5.0/grids-min.css', 103) %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css-compiled/nucleus.css', 102) %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css-compiled/template.css', 101) %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/custom.css', 100) %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/font-awesome.min.css', 100) %}
    {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/slidebars.min.css') %}

    {% if browser.getBrowser == 'msie' and browser.getVersion == 10 %}
        {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/nucleus-ie10.css') %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if browser.getBrowser == 'msie' and browser.getVersion >= 8 and browser.getVersion <= 9 %}
        {% do assets.addCss('theme://css/nucleus-ie9.css') %}
        {% do assets.addJs('theme://js/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js') %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{{ assets.css() }}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @John-MichaelL'Allier check my answer :) thanks a ton for your time , +1 to you

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a caching issue and you might need to disable caching for the parent or sub page. See [this issue](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/507) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file `css/custom.css` does't exists in the `css` directory , creating this file solved the issue.

**NOTE::-** in a default `.html` file the non-existent css file would still be loaded , but seems grav won't load a non-existent file !